John 3: Where do Jesus' Words Stop and the Narrator's Words Begin?
John 3 preserves a conservation between Jesus and Nicodemus which features Jesus teaching the idea being born anew through the Holy Spirit. My question is: where do Jesus' words stop and the narrator's words begin after this teaching concludes? Clearly Jesus is still speaking at least through verse 11:

10 Jesus answered him, “Are you the teacher of Israel, and yet you do
not understand these things? 11 “Very truly, I tell you, we speak of
what we know and testify to what we have seen, yet you do not
receive our testimony.12 If I have told you about earthly things and
you do not believe, how can you believe if I tell you about heavenly
things?

Vss. 13:15 also seem to be spoken by Jesus. But when we come to verse 16 - one of the most famous in the Christian Bible - it is not clear whether Jesus speaks or the author does:

For God so loved the world that he gave his only Son, so that everyone
who believes in him may not perish but may have eternal life.

Translators sometimes include quotation marks around this statement, but sometimes they omit them, implying that it is the narrator speaks. There are no punctuation marks in the earliest Greek manuscripts, so we cannot turn to them for help. After 3:16 the chapter continues this teaching through verse 21, in language similar to that of the gospel's prolog.

Indeed, God did not send the Son into the world to condemn the world
but in order that the world might be saved through him. 18 Those
who believe in him are not condemned, but those who do not believe are
condemned already because they have not believed in the name of the
only Son of God. 19 And this is the judgment, that the light has
come into the world, and people loved darkness rather than light
because their deeds were evil. 20 For all who do evil hate the
light and do not come to the light, so that their deeds may not be
exposed. 21 But those who do what is true come to the light, so
that it may be clearly seen that their deeds have been done in God.

Restating the question: Does Jesus or the narrator speak in John 3:16. At what point in this chapter do Jesus' words stop and the narrator's begin?

I can see no reason to suppose that 'Jesus answered and said unto him . . . . (verse 10)' does not cover all the following words until the end of verse 21. Why would anyone suppose so ?

Here's a related question.  It approaches it from the other direction, the change in tenses.   https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60159/in-john-316-why-the-shift-to-aorist-and-perfect-tense-verbs

@NigelJ... I have thought until today that "God so loved the world that he gave his only begotten son" was a statement by the evangelist. Reading it in context today, I realized this may not be the case. So I asked. I feel a little sheepish to say this, (in response to Dottard) but I also did not realize the issue has been debated for centuries.

@PerryWebb Your question did not come up when I looked for duplicates prior to posting this one.

@Dan Because my question is different but related.

@PerryWebb One possibility which I have not, yet, seen addressed (and this may answer the question of tense-changes) is that John is quoting Jesus' words throughout the passage but the first quotations are from the immediate incident and John then adds supporting words from Jesus' other conversations and discourses.

Question re-statement:

Is John 3:16-21 a continuation of Jesus' little sermon/explanation to
Nicodemus, or, an explanatory comment by the author John?

That such a question is at least 500 years old is documented by Meyer when he comments on V16:

John 3:16. Continuation of the address of Jesus to Nicodemus, onwards
to John 3:21,[162] not, as Erasmus, Rosenmüller, Kuinoel, Paulus,
Neander, Tholuck, Olshausen, Maier think (see also Bäumlein), an
explanatory meditation of the evangelist’s own; an assumption
justified neither by anything in the text nor by the word ΜΟΝΟΓΕΝΉς, a
word which must have been transferred from the language of John to the
mouth of Jesus (not vice versa, as Hengstenberg thinks), for it is
never elsewhere used by Christ, often as He speaks of His divine
sonship. See on John 1:14. The reflective character of the following
discourse is so fully compatible with the design of Christ to
instruct, and the preterites ἠγάπησαν and ἮΝ so little require to be
explained from the standing-point of a later time, that there does not
seem any sufficient basis for the intermediate view (of Lücke, De
Wette, Brückner), that in this continued account of the discourse of
Jesus, John 3:16 ff., John inserts more explanations and reflections
of his own than in the preceding part, how little soever such a
supposition would (as Kling and Hengstenberg think) militate against
the trustworthiness of John, who, in recording the longer discourses,
has exactly in his own living recollection the abundant guarantee of
substantial certainty.

Before offering my own two-cents worth on this long-standing debate, allow me to observe that the entire "gospel" of John is contained in embryonic form in its prologue; this includes:

the deity of Jesus (1:1 and 20:28)
the light of Jesus (1:4, 9, 8:12)
the supremacy of Jesus
the pre-existence of Jesus (1:1-3, 15, 3:13, 30, 8:58)
His close connection with the Father
the fact that the Father sends the Son
the humanity of Jesus
Jesus' embodiment of grace and truth
being born of God (1:13, 3:3-6)
the theme of "life" (1:4, 3:15, 16)
μονογενής (monogenes) = "unique", "only", (1:14, 18, 3:16, 18; see also 1 John 4:9)
etc

Thus, it is not surprising that the pivotal discourse with Nicodemus continues this pattern. Further in many cases, it is what Jesus says that is often the expansion of the prologue theme such as His famous statement about being the "Light of the world".
So, it is theoretically possible that John 3:16-21 is a comment by John.  However, I see it as part of the conversation between Jesus and Nicodemus for the following reasons:

The passage begins with two conjunctions, Οὕτως γὰρ (= "Thus, for") suggestion a continuation
While it has been recognized for centuries that John' "gospel" is more a work of theology than narrative (hence the ancient hagiographic title, "John the Theologian") John's theology in his gospel is always placed in the mouths and actions of the actors, and never as a comment (except for the prologue).  Hence making John 3:16-21 a comment by John would be entirely out of character with his literary style.
At the conclusion of this passage, John makes a distinct break with the phrase, Μετὰ ταῦτα (= "after these [things]") suggesting that the conversation was ended and John is about to record the next set of incidents.
in almost every case, John confines his comments to simple explanation of the flow of the story - telling what people did and never offering theological comment.

Therefore, I believe that John 3:16-21 is part of Jesus conversation with Nicodemus.

+1 thanks for this erudite response. You mention that  "John's theology in his gospel is always placed in the mouths and actions of the actors, and never as a comment (except for the prologue)." This begs the question as to whether it is Jesus or John who speaks through Jesus here.

It may be a shift from direct quotes to indirect quotes.

@DanFefferman - Ah! I see the problem.  I started from the assumption that john reports what he saw and heard (as 1 John 1 makes clear) and not simply writing an imaginary play to teach theology.
